# 64-bit double on 32-bit computer

Tags: bit, endianness, data-representation

I have an 32-bit int `0x31333337` and a 64-bit double `0x40786B6364333435`. I am asked how they will be represented on 32-bit computer with little endian representation.

The first is obvious: `37 | 33 | 33 | 31`
But the second one is not. I think that only first 16 most significant bits will be used and we will obtain: `63 6B 78 40`.

Can you say whether answers are correct?

Comment: Really bad question as there is no single correct answer.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Endianness